# How to find the maximum affordable amount of bitcoin/cryptocurrencies?

Tags: python

I am currently building a trading bot for cryptocurrencies based on time series analysis in Python. While working on defining the buy and sell signals, I am confronted with the issue of finding the maximum affordable amount of coins to buy with a given stock of cash such that the cash will not be negative. For simplicity reasons, we can assume that the minimum amount of coins to buy is 0.0001, so 0.0001 of the current crypto price. So how can I implement it in Python to find the maximum amount of 0.0001 units of a cryptocurrency with a given cash stock such that the cash won't be negative but maximally used?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  We fix a problem in existing code; we do not write code from scratch: that’s your responsibility.

Comment: Well isn't it just ```shares = cash/price``` ? if you provide a sample of your code we can help more

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for ceiling and floor math functions.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

for example if you have 10 dollars and each share is $3 you can only buy 3 shares.
or in code:

```
import math
print(math.floor(10/3))
>>>3
```

*edited to show result

Comment: Why floor? You can buy crypto (and many stocks) in fractional amounts

Comment: @OneCricketeer of course but there's a rule about working with money and using floats: don't use floats. So in my example I didn't do it the way i'm suggesting but you should use integer values of the smallest denomination. 
https://dzone.com/articles/never-use-float-and-double-for-monetary-calculatio